# ICannot figure out how to run queries for student

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Here is my code that I created for each of the tables, not sure how to join the tables to calculated the gpa's??

```
CREATE TABLE Student(SSN NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
SName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Major VARCHAR(4),
```

Comment: can you give an example of a query you have tried

Comment: Got an example?  What have you tried so far, also need to clean up that code, barely legible.

Comment: SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM Grade;  I know this gets me the average from grades table but I need to calculate the total credit hours by each student in the course table and divide that by the grade the student achieved in the grade table, not sure how to go about that??

Comment: You realize that Student has no way of linking to the other tables because the SSN doesn't match anything in the Course or Grade tables?

Comment: It matches in the grade table

Comment: Not according to your sample data it doesnt.

Comment: The tables that I was given were coded to there specs.

Comment: Ok, tables must join together on equal values.  In `Student`, `SSN` equals `1234` for the first student.  But there is no value `1234` in `Grades`.  Please update your sample to show the relationship between the tables.

Comment: Ok very sorry about that I added what was missing.

Comment: FYI.  Your edit was rejected because it took information away from the post.  The questions and answers on SO are not just for you, but for others as well who might have this same question.  Did you remove the answer check for any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because grade and SSN are in the grades table,  you dont need to join and can get the average grade like this:

This gives the average grade per student, ordered by the grade:

```
SELECT AVG(g.Grade), g.SSN
FROM Grade g
group by g.SSN
order by AVG(g.Grade)
```

If you wanted average grade per course it would look like this:

```
SELECT AVG(g.Grade), g.cno
FROM Grade g
group by g.cno
order by AVG(g.Grade)
```

However, if you need more information from student, you'd need to join to the student table:

```
select *
from (
   SELECT AVG(g.Grade) as average_grade, g.SSN
   FROM Grade g
   group by g.SSN) a
inner join Student s on a.ssn = s.ssn
```