# caculating a grade point average

Tags: mysql, sql

This sample code her just figures out the     grade average for table 3, not the true GPA : SELECT *
   FROM (
   SELECT AVG(g.Grade) as average_grade, g.SSN
   FROM Grade g
   group by g.SSN) a
   inner join Student s on a.ssn = s.ssn;

Tying to figure out the correct formula: Here is what I have came up with but it is not correct
    SELECT *
   FROM (
   SELECT SUM(Grade*CreditHour)/(SUM(CreditHour) as average_grade, g.SSN
   FROM Grade g
   group by g.SSN) a
   inner join Student s on a.ssn = s.ssn;

```
Need some help stuck on this problem?
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515164/icannot-figure-out-how-to-run-queries-for-gpa-by-student-sorted-list-by-gpa-by#comment37955486_24515164

Comment: the grade NUMER, like 1,2,3,4: like for example A=4, B=3, for the gpa

Comment: trying to figure out the true gpa not the average of the grade from table 3.

Comment: What Strawberry is insinuating is that there is no NUMBER data type in MySQL. Obviously you tagged your question incorrectly.

Comment: SQL plus is for Oracle dbms not MySQL. Oracle and MySQL are different database systems.

Comment: Sorry I did the incorrect tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you simply forgot to join the grade table with the course table. Or am I missing something?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(g.Grade*c.CreditHour) / SUM(c.CreditHour) as average_grade, 
    g.SSN 
  FROM Grade g
  INNER JOIN Course c ON c.cno = g.cno                         
  GROUP BY g.SSN
) a 
INNER JOIN Student s ON a.ssn = s.ssn;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You've accepted my answer, but tell me it's incorrect, though? What do you mean with "for course number 001 4*2/2=4"? The GPA is not per course but per student. I don't get it. If my answer doesn't suffice, please tell me what it lacks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer back after doing my calculations you were indeed correct and I was wrong, thanks!